# Keep Contents of webpage from shifting when window resized

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to html/css and trying to build a simple webpage, however the elements keep shifting when I re-size the browser window. For example if I have text in the bottom right hand corner of the screen and I make my browser window have screen I want to have to scroll over to the right too be able to see the text again. Here is my code that is not working how I wanted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            body {
                min-width: 960px;
                min-height: 960px;
            }
            #testxt {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 10px;
                right: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="testxt">Hello</div>
        </div>
    </Body>

</html>
```

I want to have to scroll over to see the hello when I re-size the window

Comment: I  can't get your question clear can you make it more clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to give the div a left distance, if you want it to stay on a fixed place.

Try adding:

```
left: 1500px;
```

Now when resizing your window, the div won't change position horizontally.
To do the same vertically, you'll have to set a top too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you can't believe I didn't figure that out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change position to fixed.

An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window.

It will not move even if the window is scrolled:

```
#testxt
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 20px;
}
```